# hacer insert en MySQL con java y JDialog dinámico

Tags: java, mysql, java-swing

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la que con un JDialog, muestro en JLabel y JTextField el contenido de una tabla de MySQL. Hasta ahí más o menos bien, pero ahora tengo un problema y es que no se como hacer un insert en la tabla ya que yo puedo elegir cualquier BD y cualquier tabla de esa BD, pero dezconozco como hacer una consulta con java para que reconozca los values que se cargan automáticamente... No se si me explico correctamente. Adjunto un par de imágenes para que se pueda ver lo que digo.

Aquí selecciono una tabla al azar para mostrar el JDialog dinámico

[image: Primera elección de tabla y cargando sus datos]

Aquí selecciono otra tabla y hace cambiar el Jdialog

[image: Otra tabla seleccionada]

La pregunta es, como se ven en las imágenes, hay un boton de insertar. Como capturo los datos del JDialog dinámico para poder hacer un insert tabla seleccionada values(valores del JDialog)??

*******JDialog************

public class DialogoInserccion extends JDialog{

```
public DialogoInserccion(String[] columnas, Object[] filas, String tabla, String BD){
    super((JFrame) null, true);
    this.filas = filas;
    this.columnas = columnas;
    this.tabla = tabla;
    this.BD = BD;

    this.conexion = conexion;

    etiquetas = new JLabel[columnas.length];
    campos = new JTextField[columnas.length];

    for(int i=0; i<columnas.length;i++){
        JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel(columnas[i]);
        JTextField campo = new JTextField();
        etiquetas[i] = etiqueta;
        campos[i] = campo;
        this.add(etiqueta);
        this.add(campo);
    }

    btInsertar = new JButton("Insertar");

    this.add(btInsertar);

    btInsertar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                MySQL.conecta("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + BD, "pepe", "pepa");
                PreparedStatement prst = null;

                for(int i=0; i<etiquetas.length;i++){
                   // System.out.println(etiquetas[i].getText());

                }
                MySQL.ejecutaConsulta("SELECT * FROM " + tabla);
                ResultSet rs = MySQL.getRs();
                String[] columnas = new String[rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()];


                for(int i=0; i<columnas.length;i++){
                    columnas[i] = rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
                    System.out.println("columnas: " + columnas[i]);
                }


                for(int i=0; i<columnas.length;i++){
                    MySQL.ejecutaConsultaAccion("INSERT INTO " +tabla+"("+columnas[i]+")" +
                            " VALUES("+campos[i].getText()+")");
                    System.out.println("Tabla: " + columnas[i]);
                }


            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Clase no encontrada");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problema al ejecutar la consulta en diálogo " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 0, 10));
    pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

**Actualización**

He conseguido capturar los elementos de mi JDialog dinámico, pero tengo algún error al montar la consulta SQL y no soy capaz de verlo. Adjunto fuente:

```
btInsertar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                MySQL.conecta("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + BD, "pepe", "pepa");
                MySQL.ejecutaConsulta("SELECT * FROM " + tabla);

                for(int i=0; i<campos.length; i++){
                    MySQL.ejecutaConsultaAccion("INSERT INTO "+ tabla +"("+etiquetas[i].getText()+")" +
                            " values("+campos[i].getText()+")");
                }

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Clase no encontrada");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + "\n");
            }
        }
    });
```

**Actualización 2**

[image: salida sout]

El error lo muestra cerca de cada campos[i].getText(), es decir si inserto pepe, me devuelve que el error esta cerca de pepe

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿De qué manera has creado tus `JDialog`? ¿Es un sólo `JDialog` que cambia de acuerdo a la tabla? o ¿Has creado diferentes clases por cada `JDialog`? En ambos casos, sería oportuno que adjuntes el código de cómo lo haces.

Comment: @C.Rodriguez gracias por tu respuesta. En mi pregunta, he adjuntado el código completo de mi JDialog. Es un solo JDialog que cambia de acuerdo a la tabla, así es.

Answer (score 1):

El error lo tienes al montar la consulta de insert. Lo que te ocurre es que intentas insertar una linea por cada campo, de manera que en vez de crearte un registro te crearía tres o el número de campos que tuvieras (digo 3 por el segundo pantallazo que muestras)

Tendrías que sustituir dentro del try, después de realizar la conexión, la parte del for por algo así:

```
//Creas variables auxiliares.
String etiquetas_bbdd = String.Empty;
String campos_bbdd = String.Empty;

//Recorres los campos y los metes en las variables auxiliares, para montar la consulta más adelante.
for(int i = 0; i < campos.length; i++){
    etiquetas_bbdd += etiquetas[i].getText();
    campos_bbdd += "'" + campos[i].getText() + "'"; // Sólo varchar

    // Este IF nos indica si NO estamos en el último campo.
    // En caso de que ESTEMOS en el último campo, NO debería agregarse la coma, es decir, 
    // pasaría al ELSE (que no existe, por lo tanto no se agregaría)
    if (i + 1 < campos.length) {
        etiquetas_bbdd += ", ";
        campos_bbdd += ", ";
    }
}

//Aqui montas tu consulta de inserción
MySQL.ejecutaConsultaAccion("INSERT INTO "+ tabla +"(" + etiquetas_bbdd + ")" + " values(" + campos_bbdd + ")");
```

Esto debería solucionar tu problema. El tema del substring lo he quitado porque con las modificaciones propuestas ya no es necesario. Además, en mi opinión, este código es más legible.

Comment: @daviserraalonso, Esta respuesta me parece apropiada, debido a que se crea la sentencia del INSERT correctamente: `INSERT INTO (campo1, campo2, campo3..., campoN) VALUES (valor1, valor2, valor3..., valorN);`.

Comment: La única observación (y creo que les pasó a ambos) es que los campos declarados como `String` (`Varchar`) en la base de datos, deberían tener comillas simples, y si no las agregan les lanzará error (por sintaxis)

Comment: Mil gracias as los dos, he hecho lo que me has dicho Miguel, pero me devuelve que desconoce el campo ciudad. @C.Rodriguez he puesto los campos_bbdd entre comillas simples y tampoco funciona

Comment: En este caso, sería bueno que indiques cuales son tus campos en la base de datos y su tipo de dato, sólo para estar seguros que los datos que estás enviando son correctos. Por ejemplo, no puedes agregarle comillas simples a un entero, eso te generaría un error, tampoco puedes hacer un `INSERT` a un campo auto incrementable

Comment: @C.Rodriguez Lo que pretendo con esta aplicación es que sea universal, que pueda insertar en cualquier tabla que yo seleccione, para eso el JDialog dinámico. Seleccionando una tabla en concret, los datos son int, varchar y double. Añado una nueva imagen en mi pregunta, donde hago un sout del contenido

Comment: En ese caso, te recomiendo leer sobre los [VarArgs en Java](https://darkbyteblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/java-argumentos-variables/). Utilicé esa misma técnica para crear un `INSERT` genérico (que funcione para todos).

Comment: @C.Rodriguez creo que acabo de ver el error, el compañero Miguel, me ha comentado que revisara los substring que fueran 1 o 3 en vez de 2. Pero parece que no es ninguno de estos, puesto que en el último campo, mete un ',' y provoca error de sintaxis...

Comment: Con un `if` podrías evitar las últimas comas, si @Miguel Martinez me da autorización le podría agregar el código.

Comment: Estaría agradecido @C.Rodriguez

Comment: Hola a todos. Muchas gracias a los que están ayudando a completar la respuesta. Por supuesto, @C.Rodriguez, agrega lo que veas necesario. Como digo en la respuesta, no disponía de un ide y lo puse de memoria. davidserraalonso, es importante tener en cuenta el tipo de dato, que como dice C.Rodriguez con un if se soluciona. Voy a completar la respuesta con lo comentado, y si falta algo, decidlo y si podéis, agregadlo sin problemas.

Comment: es mucho mas facil, borrar la ultima coma,que hacer un if en cada pasada, que para colmo esta mal duplicado, porque si una variable esta vacia la otra tambien.